# Resolve with parameter from other constructor with unity

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, unity-container

I'm using Unity and inject all my dependencies. Let's say that I have a `Manager` class like so

```
public class Manager : IManager
{
    public Manager(IRepository repository, string customerName) { }
}
```

And a repository class like:

```
public class Repository : IRepository
{
    public Repository(string customerName) { }
}
```

I'm using WCF and will resolve the manager and the repository once per request. I register all my types at service startup, but at startup i do not know the "customerName"-parameter. This will be passed as a parameter to the WCF-service. Which will resolve the manager like this:

```
public class Service
{
    private IUnityContainer _container;

    public Service(IUnityContainer container)
    {
        _container = container;
    }

    public void ServiceCall(string customerName)
    {
        var manager = _container.Resolve<IManager<T>>(
            new ParameterOverrides { { "customerName", customerName} });
        manager.DoSomething();
    }
}
```

This way I can inject the `customerName`-parameter into the manager on each request. This works fine. But now I also need to inject it to the repository. **Is there any way to inject the `customerName` to the repository-class as well?**

I know I can set it manually later, but I would like to have this in the constructor. Also, I don't want the Service to know about the Repository, so I don't want to manually override that parameter.

I could resolve the `IRepository` with the container in the constructor in the Manager, but i rather just inject it if it's possible.

Comment: You are already doing it correctly. When you use `ParameterOverrides`, it will inject the specified value into any parameter named "customerName" in the whole object graph that you are resolving, not just the direct one. Doesn't your current code work? Can you show how you are registering your types?

Comment: You are correct. It actually works, I just didn't try it in my actual case since I assumed that it was only injected into the "first layer".

Comment: Great! Please note that I was answering your question directly. However, you are using the container as a service locator [which is an anti-pattern](http://yacoubsoftware.blogspot.com/2015/10/object-composability-another-reason-why.html). Steven's answer below explains more about issues with the way your are doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I register all my types at service startup, but at startup i do not
>   know the "customerName"-parameter

In other words, your `customerName` parameter is runtime data. Injecting runtime data into components during the components' initialization [is an anti-pattern](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=99).

There are two possible solutions to your problem, but in your your case, the most likely solution is to pass through the parameter through the public API as follows:

```
public class Service
{
    private readonly IManager _manager;

    public Service(IManager manager) {
        _manager = manager;
    }

    public void ServiceCall(string customerName) {
        _manager.DoSomething(customerName);
    }
}
```

Here the `IManager` interface is changed so that the `customerName` is passed through the `DoSomething` method. Because the runtime value isn't needed anymore during construction, there is no need to inject the Unity container into the `Service` (which is a form of the [Service Locator anti-pattern](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/)).

For the second option, please read [this article](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=99).

Comment: I believe you are right. It's an anti-pattern, but in my case it was more convenient since ALL my methods rely on that specific value. And I only need to process it once (which I did in the constructor). But sometimes you need to face reality and re-think your approach. I will pass it as parameters instead. Thank you.

Comment: @smoksnes: Well, if it is a contextual value, you can go with the second approach and inject an `ICustomerContext` abstraction into the `Repository`.

Comment: @smoksnes: That article contains two examples. In the second example the use of `currentUserId` and `now` are refactored to `IUserContext` and `ITimeProvider`, which is similar to your `ICustomerContext`.