# How can I register a type with dynamic string parameters in it's constructor at Composition root?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, unity-container

I have these constructors:

```
    public Configurator(string workingDirectory, string siteExclusions) : this(directory, exclusions, new ServerManager(), new DirectoryCheck())
    {
    }

    public Configurator(string directory, string exclusions, IServerManager manager, IDirectoryCheck directoryCheck)
    {
        this.manager = manager;
        this.directoryCheck = directoryCheck;
        if (exclusions != null)
        {
            // do stuff
        }

        this.directory = directory;
    }
```

Where `directory` and `exclusions` are created by the creating code, within a winforms application. E.g.

```
        using (var configurator = new Configurator(this.CalculatedDirectory(), this.exclusions))
        {
            var output = configurator.ConfigureIIS();
            this.txtOutput.Text = output;
        }
```

I am trying to remove the first constructor and retrofit the Unity DI Container. I have started to make this composition root, to be called from `Program`:

```
public static class ApplicationRoot
{
    private static readonly Lazy<IUnityContainer> Container = new Lazy<IUnityContainer>(() =>
    {
        var container = new UnityContainer();
        RegisterTypes(container);
        return container;
    });

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the configured Unity container.
    /// </summary>
    public static IUnityContainer FetchConfiguredContainer()
    {
        return Container.Value;
    }

    private static void RegisterTypes(IUnityContainer unityContainer)
    {
        unityContainer.RegisterType<IServerManager, ServerManager>();
        unityContainer.RegisterType<IDirectoryCheck, DirectoryCheck>();
    }
}
```

But how do I deal with the strings `directory` and `exclusions`?

I know I can use `new InjectionConstructor("foo")` in my Composition Root, but I don't know the values at that point.

Comment: "But how do I deal with the strings directory and exclusions?". Are these values configuration values (fixed for the lifetime of the application) or runtime values (such as request specific values)?

Comment: Hah! Interesting that I just posted an answer where I quote @Steven ... :)

Answer (score 0):

I asked a similiar question a while ago - [Resolve with parameter from other constructor with unity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33801531/resolve-with-parameter-from-other-constructor-with-unity)

As [Steven](https://stackoverflow.com/users/264697/steven) so elegantly put it:

> In other words, your [variable name] parameter is runtime data. Injecting
>   runtime data into components during the components' initialization is
>   [an anti-pattern](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=99).

The way I solved it was to create a container that hold the value. In my case I was able to bind it to the WCF-context. But it could be hold for a specific thread, request or session instead.

Here's an example:

```
public interface IOperationContext<T>
{
    IDictionary<string, T> Items { get; }
}

public class ThreadOperationContext<T> : IOperationContext<T>
{
    [ThreadStatic]
    private static Dictionary<string, T> _items;

    public IDictionary<string, T> Items
    {
        get
        {
            if (_items == null)
            {
                _items = new Dictionary<string, T>();
            }
            return _items;
        }
    } 
}

public class WcfOperationContext<T> : IExtension<OperationContext>
{
    private readonly IDictionary<string, T> _items;

    private WcfOperationContext()
    {
        _items = new Dictionary<string, T>();
    }

    public IDictionary<string, T> Items
    {
        get { return _items; }
    }

    public static WcfOperationContext<T> Current
    {
        get
        {
            WcfOperationContext<T> context = OperationContext.Current.Extensions.Find<WcfOperationContext<T>>();
            if (context == null)
            {
                context = new WcfOperationContext<T>();
                OperationContext.Current.Extensions.Add(context);
            }
            return context;
        }
    }

    public void Attach(OperationContext owner) { }
    public void Detach(OperationContext owner) { }
}

/// <summary>
/// Provides a collection that will be unique for every operation context.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
public class WcfOperationContextWrapper<T> : IOperationContext<T>
{
    public IDictionary<string, T> Items
    {
        get { return WcfOperationContext<T>.Current.Items; }
    }
}
```

Then you can inject an `IOperationContext<string>` when the variable `workingDirectory` is supposed to be set. Then you can inject it in the implementation where you need it and have the variable set for you.

Example:

```
public class MySetter
{
    public MySetter(IOperationContext<string> stringContainer)
    {
        stringContainer["workingDirectory"] = "foo";
    }
}

public class MyGetter
{
    public MyGetter(IOperationContext<string> stringContainer)
    {
        var workingDirectory = stringContainer["workingDirectory"];
    }
}
```

The code above will work with WCF and Thread-unique processes. But, as I'm sure you know, there are several risks when binding information for a specific thread. But I hope it can guide you in the right direction. The point is to bind it to a container and use the container instead of a string. You can use `Session` instead of `ThreadStatic` if it's user specific and so on.