# C# unable to access property of dependency injected class in another class

Tags: c#-4.0, dependency-injection, unity-container

I have the following `Processor` class defined:

```
public class Processor : IProcessor
{
    private IRepository _repository;
    private IMongoWrapper _mongoWrapper;

    public Processor(IRepository repository, IMongoWrapper mongoWrapper)
    {   
        _repository = repository;
        _mongoWrapper = mongoWrapper;
    }

    public void Process()
    {
        _mongoWrapper.Initialise("path");

        _repository.Save();
    }
}
```

The `Processor` class gets injected with the following two classes at runtime:

```
public class MongoWrapper : IMongoRWrapper
{
        private string _fileName;

        public void Initialise(string path)
        {
            _fileName = path;
        };

        public void Log()
        {
            IsInitialised();
        }

        private void IsInitialised()
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_fileName))
                throw new InvalidOperationException(
                    Resource.MongoRepositoryHelper_must_be_initialised);
        }
}

public class Repository : IRepository
{
    private IMongoWrapper _mongoWrapper;
    public Repository(IMongoWrapper mongoWrapper)
    {   
        _mongoWrapper = mongoWrapper;
    }       

    public void Save()
    {
        _mongoWrapper.Log();
    }
}
```

I am using Unity for dependency injection.

The property, `_fileName` of `MongoWrapper` initialised in `Processor.Process()` method is not available, when i access the property in `Repository` class.

Can anyone please tell me what i am doing wrong here?

It worked when i made the `_fileName` in `MongoWrapper` as static field. Is this the right way?

Comment: Why do you need the `Process` to pass on the path to the `MongoWrapper`? That design smells.

Comment: The process method is actually called by a windows service, and the path is the filename which the service picked up from the folder location. so it varies always.

Comment: So it varies every time the `Proces` method is called, or is this some configuration value that doesn't change while the windows service is running?

Answer (score 2):

> The property, `_fileName` of `MongoWrapper` initialised in
>   `Processor.Process()` method is not available, when i access the
>   property in `Repository` class.

When you say *is not available*, I assume that you're meaning that the string `_fileName` hasn't been assigned a value. If you mean something else, you may disregard from this answer.

The reason why it hasn't been assigned is probably because you're injecting two different references, and using `TransientLifetimeManager`, which is default.

[Understanding Lifetime Managers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660872(v=pandp.20).aspx)

> When you register a type in configuration, or by using the
>   RegisterType method, the default behavior is for the container to use
>   a transient lifetime manager. It creates a new instance of the
>   registered, mapped, or requested type each time you call the Resolve
>   or ResolveAll method or when the dependency mechanism injects
>   instances into other classes.

This means that when you resolve `Processor` it will get one instance of `MongoWrapper` and when you resolve `Repository` you will get another. It's newed up at every injection.

Think of it like this:

```
var processor = new Processor(new Repository(new MongoWrapper()), new MongoWrapper());
```

As you see, it's creating two different `MongoWrapper`. There's a couple of ways to solve this.

**1.** Use another `LifetimeManager`. `PerResolveLifetimeManager` is probably the one you want.

> For this lifetime manager the behavior is
>   like a TransientLifetimeManager, but also provides a signal to the
>   default build plan, marking the type so that instances are reused
>   across the build-up object graph. In the case of recursion, the
>   singleton behavior applies where the object has been registered with
>   the PerResolveLifetimeManager.

Register it like so:

```
container.RegisterType<IMongoWrapper, MongoWraper>(new PerResolveLifetimeManager());
```

Think of it like this:

```
var mongoWrapper = new MongoWrapper();
var processor = new Processor(new Repository(mongoWrapper), mongoWrapper);
```

---

**2.** Use `ContainerControlledLifetimeManager`, will make your `IMongoWrapper`a singleton and thus use the same reference all the time. Depending on how you use IMongoWrapper this may, or may not, be what you want. In this scenario, it will practially be like setting `_fileName` to be `static` (as you mentioned), but instead the whole `IMongoWrapper` is `static`.

> ContainerControlledLifetimeManager which registers an existing object
>   as a singleton instance. For this lifetime manager Unity returns the
>   same instance of the registered type or object each time you call the
>   Resolve or ResolveAll method or when the dependency mechanism injects
>   instances into other classes.

```
container.RegisterType<IMongoWrapper, MongoWraper>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
```

---

**3.** Assign `IMongoWrapper` manually. However, this would defeat the whole purpose of using IoC.

```
public class Processor : IProcessor
{
    private IRepository _repository;
    private IMongoWrapper _mongoWrapper;

    public Processor(IRepository repository, IMongoWrapper mongoWrapper)
    {   
        _repository = repository;
        _mongoWrapper = mongoWrapper;
        _repository.SetWrapper(mongoWrapper);
    }

    public void Process()
    {
        _mongoWrapper.Initialise("path");

        _repository.Save();
    }
}
```

And your repository:

```
public class Repository : IRepository
{
    private IMongoWrapper _mongoWrapper;
    public Repository()
    {   
    }   

    public void SetWrapper(IMongoWrapper wrapper)
    {
        _mongoWrapper = wrapper;
    }

    public void Save()
    {
        _mongoWrapper.Log();
    }
}
```

---

With all that said, I must say that I agree with [Steven](https://stackoverflow.com/users/264697/steven) regarding your design. Do you really need to inject the same reference of `IMongoWrapper` into both classes? And does `Processor` really need to set a value in `IMongoWrapper` in order to make it usable for `Repository`? It creates sort of a weird dependency, which may come back to haunt you later. An answer that solves the design might have been better, but I choose to focus on the actual task.

**UPDATE:**

> Which is the best solution do you think? To set the lifetimemanager as
>   singleton or set the value for the filename in the repository class?

Well, to me it sounds as `_fileName` is a context variable, which is used throughout one request/thread/cycle. Therefore you could handle it accordingly. Either set the `MongoWrapper` as a singleton, if that's what you actually want. And let it be responsible for keeping `_filePath`.

But if you just want to keep `_fileName` as a contextvariable for a specific scope (eg. thread or request), I wrote [an answer for a similiar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37565494/how-can-i-register-a-type-with-dynamic-string-parameters-in-its-constructor-at/37566670#37566670), from which you can use the code. The idéa is that instead of depending on another a specific reference of `IMongoWrapper`, you could share a container for `_fileName`. For [`IOperationContext`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37565494/how-can-i-register-a-type-with-dynamic-string-parameters-in-its-constructor-at/37566670#37566670), check the code in [the answer I wrote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37565494/how-can-i-register-a-type-with-dynamic-string-parameters-in-its-constructor-at/37566670#37566670), which in turn is based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33801531/resolve-with-parameter-from-other-constructor-with-unity).

First a class for holding FilePath. It could be just a string as well.

```
public class ContextInfo : IContextInfo
{
    public string FilePath {get; set;}
}

public interface IContextInfo
{
    string FilePath {get; set;}
}
```

Then a wrapper that uses `IOperationContext<IContextInfo>`.

```
public class RequestContext : IRequestContext
{
    private readonly IOperationContext<IContextInfo> _operationContext;

    public RequestContext(IOperationContext<IContextInfo> operationContext)
    {
        _operationContext = operationContext;
    }

    public IContextInfo ContextInfo
    {
        get
        {
            if (_operationContext.Items.ContainsKey("ContextInfoString"))
            {
                return _operationContext.Items["ContextInfoString"];
            }
            return null;
        }
        set
        {
            _operationContext.Items["ContextInfoString"] = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Inject the `IRequestContext` to your processor.

```
public class Processor : IProcessor
{
    private IRepository _repository;
    private IMongoWrapper _mongoWrapper;
    private IRequestContext _requestContext

    public Processor(IRepository repository, IMongoWrapper mongoWrapper, IRequestContext requestContext)
    { 
        _requestContext = requestContext
        _repository = repository;
        _mongoWrapper = mongoWrapper;
    }

    public void Process()
    {
        // Set the context variable.
        _requestContext.ContextInfo = new ContextInfo { FilePath = "path" });
        // Now it will be set for a specific lifetime.
        _repository.Save();
    }
}
```

Now the variable is set, and you can use it wherever...

```
public class MongoWrapper : IMongoRWrapper
{
    private IRequestContext _requestContext;
    public MongoWrapper(IRequestContext requestContext)
    {
        _requestContext = requestContext;
    }

    private void IsInitialised()
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_requestContext.ContextInfo.FilePath))
            throw new InvalidOperationException(
                Resource.MongoRepositoryHelper_must_be_initialised);
    }
}
```

But again, it all depends on how you tend to use `fileName`, and what it's lifetime should be. Think about the ownership of the variable. Should it be owned by `IMongoWrapper`? Or is it something that is used throughout the application. The questions for those answers should guide you in the right direction.

Comment: Thank you for the brilliant explanation about the Unity lifetimemanagers. I have never come across such a wonderful explanation. Thanks once again. Yes, as Steven has mentioned i can see some code smell. Which is the best solution do you think? To set the lifetimemanager as singleton or set the value for the filename in the repository class? I am not very experienced in these IOCs

Comment: I've updated my answer, which primarily focuses on the ownership for `fileName`. It contains an alternative solution to the problem, but you might want to rethink the responsibilities for your classes.